# HOW TO USE escpos-2.2 jar & jSerialComm-2.5.0 jar to PRINT RECEIPT ON THERMAL RECEIPT PRINTER

Tags: java, escpos

I am building a POS desktop application with Java that prints Transaction Receipt using a Thermal Printer. I found out that I can use escpos and JSerialComm Java APIs to achieve this. I copied sample code from GitHub to tryout if the APIs will work. Below is the code that is supposedly should work, but returns a NullPointerExceptionError.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. So what should I do to at least printout the "Hello World" just to see if my app can actually get through to the printer. Help!

```
package com;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.EscPosWriter;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.CharacterCodeTable;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.CutA;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.Height;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.Justification;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.Pin;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.PulseTime;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.enums.Width;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.serial.SerialFactory;
import com.github.terrytsai.escpos.serial.config.SerialConfig;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class PrinterClass {

    private static PrinterClass printer = null;
    private static  OutputStream out;
    private static EscPosWriter escPos;

    private PrinterClass(){
        initSerial();
    }

    protected static void writeReceipt(){
        System.out.println("Receipt started...");
        escPos = new EscPosWriter(out)
        .initialize()
        .setCharacterCodeTable(CharacterCodeTable.PC437)
        .setJustification(Justification.CENTER)
        .setCharacterSize(Width.X3, Height.X3)
        .setEmphasize(true)
        .text("HELLO WORLD")
        .printAndFeedLines(5)
        .cut(CutA.PARTIAL)
        .sendRealTimeRequestPulse(Pin.TWO, PulseTime.FOUR);
        System.out.println("Receipt done!");
    }

    private static PrinterClass getInstance(){
        if(printer == null){
            printer = new PrinterClass();
        }
        return printer;
    }

    private void initSerial(){
        SerialPort port = SerialFactory.com(3, SerialConfig.CONFIG_9600_8N1());
        port.openPort();
        out = port.getOutputStream();
        port.closePort();
      }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        PrinterClass pc = PrinterClass.getInstance();
        pc.writeReceipt();
    }
}
```

"I expected it to print the receipt. But I get an error:"

"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.terrytsai.escpos.EscPosWriter.write(EscPosWriter.java:1345)
    at com.github.terrytsai.escpos.EscPosWriter.initialize(EscPosWriter.java:1213)
    at com.PrinterClass.writeReceipt(PrinterClass.java:30)
    at com.PrinterClass.main(PrinterClass.java:58)
```

"

Comment: I believe the problem is that the init function is opening and closing the port.

Answer (score 0):

there're serveral com ports on a PC generally, try to figure out which is your printer's port, it's not necessarily be 3. Update initSerial method accordingly.

Comment: I have tried to change the  serial port number from 1 through 5 but still the error is sustained. By the way am using a USB interface not necessarily a serial port.

Comment: How about the question now?